# Objective C: How can I render Chinese fonts in OpenGL?

Tags: objective-c, ios, unicode, opengl-es, fonts

Is there anyway to render Chinese fonts without using bitmaps for IOS? If so, any links or help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What apis are you using? Is this iOS or desktop development?

Comment: Sorry for that, yes it's for iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, loading the characters into textures or a texture atlas is the only way to do this. This is how I do text regardless of the font (unicode, ascii, Chinese, English, all the same).

Check out NeHe, my bible after the Red Book.

http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/2d_texture_font/18002/

Comment: Gotcha. Is there a certain technique to go about this or troubles I need to know before I start?

Comment: I don't know how many characters/symbols you need, but if it's substantial you may only want to include the ones you need. You may need to do a hybrid approach with mipmapping if you plan to display text of various sizes and want them to look good/draw faster.

I say start out with that technique and then judge performance on what you should do next. It's at least a start.

Comment: I would avoid mipmapping, since it tends to produce fairly poor results, plus you wind up fighting your texture atlas with larger and larger required borders around each character.  For (almost free!) high resolution, low storage opengl text rendering you should use signed distance field textures for now- see http://www.valvesoftware.com/publications/2007/SIGGRAPH2007_AlphaTestedMagnification.pdf - though they report terrifying offline computation times in this paper, there exist several optimized solutions (which are also simple to implement) that will execute in milliseconds on a modern cpu.